# What does the exclamation mark in C language mean?

Tags: c

I was reading a code and I found these "!" all over the place what is it supposed to do ? this is a part from the code I found it in :

```
 if (!piocherMot(motSecret))
    exit(0);
```

piocherMot is a function in another file while "motsecret" is a variable in my main code.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Comment: For the future, try asking Google your question first. Searching "What does the exclamation mark in C language mean" in Google has many relevant results.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
!
```

is **logical NOT** operator & its a unary operator i.e it takes only one operand, result of this operator is either **true(1)** or **false(0)**. Truth table of logical NOT operator is

```
 A    !A
----------
| 0  |  1 |
| 1  |  0 |
----------
```

Hence if `piocherMot(motSecret)` results in **true** i.e `!1` which is `0` then `if` block will not get executes, in reverse case it gets executes.

```
if(!1) { /* 0 i.e if block won't executes */
}
```

And

```
if(!0) { /* 1 i.e if blocks executes */
}
```

Comment: why downvoting ? It's the answer, even thougth that the question is really basic.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you guys would want from an answer to this question. This covers it IMHO.